# gradle - copying directory - Issue

Tags: directory, gradle

I have an issue with copying files in gradle. Here is a snippet of `build.gradle`:

```
task mydir() {
    new File("build/models").mkdir()
}

task copyTask(dependsOn:mydir, type: Copy){ 

   from 'src/test/groovy/models'
   into 'build/models'

   from 'src/test/groovy/test.groovy'
   into 'build/'
}
```

The issue here is in the first copy, that is, *test.groovy* is copied into *build*. But the first copy, where I am copying all the files in *src/../models* into *build/models* is not working. It simply copies the files into *build* directory only. My *build/models* remain empty. Can someone please tell me where what I'm doing wrong? I also have a separate task to create *build/models* directory prior to *copyTask* execution.

Comment: I use copy method instead of type:Copy, it worked. Not sure what is the reason behind it. THe documentation says, the copy type does up-to-date check. whereas copy() method do not check.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The build script contains the following mistakes:

1. The directory is created when `mydir` is *configured*, not when it is *executed*. (This means the directory will be created on every build invocation, regardless of which tasks get executed.)
2. `new File('some/path')` creates a path relative to the current working directory of the Gradle process, not a path relative to the project directory. Always use `project.file()` instead.
3. A `Copy` task can only have a single top-level `into`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
task mydir {
    doLast {
        mkdir('build/models')
    }
}

task copyTask(dependsOn: mydir, type: Copy) {
    into 'build'
    from 'src/test/groovy/test.groovy'
    into('models') {
        from 'src/test/groovy/models'
    }
}
```

The `Copy` task will create `build/models` automatically, so there is likely no need to have the `mydir` task. It's odd to use `build` as the target directory of a `Copy` task (should use a subdirectory).

Answer (score -1):

In gradle, the copy task could only have single 'into' target with multiple froms.

The second 'into' override the first 'into' value and that's why it's only copied into 'build/' not 'build/models''

You may want to have a separate copy task or use ant.copy instead.

Comment: You are right regarding the overriding. However, a `Copy` task can have any number of independent *copy actions*. All they need to have in common is a "base" target directory (the top-level `into`).